# Customize the inbuilt django model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on django model forms with ajax where I have three dependent dropdown options. I want to customize the default value in django model form with an input of foreign key with dropdown select option of '---------' I want to replace that with a text that acts as a 'label'.

Here is my image.

[image: Text]

I want to have something that would show as below if I used html form select:

```
<select id="cars" name="cars">
   <option selected disabled hidden value="">Cars</option> # Value that would act like this one
   <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
   <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to this [topic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) from the official `django` docs:

> Unless **blank=False** is set on the field along with a default then a label containing "---------" will be rendered with the select box. To **override this behavior**, **add a tuple to choices containing None**; e.g. (None, 'Your String For Display').

for the last two dropdowns which are dynamically rendered with ajax calls you can prepand the result set with `(None, 'Your String For Display')`